# How do I create a tag based community for our sdk and suite of softwares for our company?

Tags: moderators, communication, wiki

We have our own set of SDKs.
We want to build out our community over StackOverflow for the developers.

What is the way to build such a community?

Answer (score 2):

You can create tags on Stack Overflow by simply adding a comma (,) after every proposed tag that doesn't currently exist in our system, When creating your new tags for your company, bear in mind that tags:

- must be no longer than 35 characters
- must use any of these character set `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`

Once the tag has been set click the Review your question button and once your question has been published, the tag has been created and can be populated.

Also, future questions that have to do with the improvement/questions of our Stack Overflow system all goes into our [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Is that it ? Is it only based and or connected to the reputation of a person here ?

Comment: @ShadabK Users with enough reputation can create tags so that the community can then populate them with content. Part of earning enough reputation means that you're trusted to edit content and create tags on the platform.